# How to Mock a named constructor dependency

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, unity-container

I have an MVC controller that has the following signature:

```
 public AccountController(
            IRulesFacade rulesFacade,
            [Dependency("personAppClient")] IAppClient personAppClient,
            [Dependency("notificationsClient")] IAppClient notificationsClient, 
            ITransformer<ExpandoObject> transformer)
```

You will notice that there are two CTOR properties which are the same Interface type but which are named differently.

In my Unity configuration I have the following lines of code:

```
 container.RegisterType<IAppClientConfigProvider, AppClientConfigProvider>("personAppClient", new InjectionConstructor(
                new ResolvedParameter<IAppClient>("personAppClient"),
                personBaseUrl));
container.RegisterType<IAppClientConfigProvider, AppClientConfigProvider>("notificationsClient", new InjectionConstructor(                    
                new ResolvedParameter<IAppClient>("notificationsClient"), 
                notificationsBaseUrl));
```

In my UnitTest I have the following with some related Setup code:

```
MockAppClient = new Mock<IAppClient>();

MockAppClient.Setup(ac => ac.AddAsync<ExpandoObject>(It.IsAny<ExpandoObject>()))
             .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(User));
```

My question is how do I create a Mock that can provide the necessary "name" for the Dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two separate mocks of the dependencies and pass that to the SUT

```
// Arrange
var personAppClientMock = new Mock<IAppClient>();
personAppClientMock.Setup(_ => _.AddAsync(It.IsAny<ExpandoObject>()))
                   .ReturnsAsync(User);

var notificationsClientMock = new Mock<IAppClient>();
notificationsClientMock.Setup(_ => _.AddAsync(It.IsAny<ExpandoObject>()))
                       .ReturnsAsync(SomeOtherObject);

//...other related setup code

var sut = new AccountController(
                  rulesFacadeMock.Object, 
                  personAppClientMock.Object, 
                  notificationsClientMock.Object, 
                  transformerMock.Object);

// Act
//...
```

Comment: Ok, thanks Nkosi, that's a good answer but is there a way to mock a "named" constructor property?

Comment: @Redeemed1, "named" constructor property refers to the container which I believe is not being used in the unit test, making mocking it irrelevant.

Comment: Hmm, I take your point but in this case the [Dependency("")] attribute on the ctor param is a means of identifying the correct instantiation of the parameter. Nevertheless your answer is a good one so I'll mark it as the Answer. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Redeemed1 You are correct `[Dependency("")] attribute on the ctor param is a means of identifying the correct instantiation of the parameter` to the DI/IoC container when actual code is running. That is what I am hoping you understand. It has no bearing on the unit test in any way unless the DI/IoC container is being used as part of the unit test which would change it to an integration test. Glad to help, Happy code!!!